# Can CodeCommit and CodePipeline/CodeBuild handle a full CI workflow?

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

I am wondering if it's possible to move from Jenkins to CodeBuild, and from Gitlab/Github to CodeCommit and keep a standard CI workflow.

I mean, push on a new branch on CodeCommit -> CodePipeline get triggered -> Clone the branch that triggered the event -> execute a created CodeBuild project that run tests -> send back the result to CodeCommit so he can display the status of the commit (failed/succeed).

CodeBuild seems great but looks like CodeCommit still too basic to keep that "classic Workflow" we usually use in software development.

But i hope i missed the way to enable CodeCommit and CodePipeline doing the full job, do you know about it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It can be done. I use git to push a production branch to CodeCommit. CodePipeline is triggered by the push, uses CodeBuild to build & test the latest push. The artifacts are then pushed to CodeDeploy which pushes my code out either to Lambda or EC2 instances.

The whole process is very streamlined.